# Execute pentaho job completely for first row before starting job for second row

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

My root job which has two steps,

Transformation Executor(to copy rows to results) & a Job Executor(Executing for each input row)

what I want is, that my sub-job should execute completely for first incoming row before it start execution for second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the `Job executor step` and check the box `Execute for every input row`.
Tell me if it is not what you need.

Comment: I am checking the box `Execute for every input row` and root job is running accordingly. but actual processing is happening in the sub job. I want my sub-job to execute serially for every input row.

Comment: I do not understand. If our setup is what I think it is, the main job will first execute the transformation, when completed start the sub-job for row 1 of results, when completed start the sub-job fro row 2 of results, when completed start sub-job for row 3 of results. Is it what you want ? If not please provide a description of what your sub-job is intended to do.

Comment: yes, that's what I needed. I created wrapper jobs for all the transformations in my sub-job and now it is running perfectly. Thanks @AlainD

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify a different value than 1 on `Change Number Of Copies To Start` (Right click on any Transformation Entry to see that option), that will always be the expected behavior.

If the number is greater than 1 then the `Job Executor` will have that number of copies running in parallel, distributing the input rows (for example, 100 input rows, with 10 copies, each copy will execute 10 rows no matter what).